# JMS message - associate with Queue

Tags: jms, message-queue

Having a jms message, which method I can use to get the queue from which it came?

I think it should be something like:

```
message.getStringProperty("OriginatingQueue")
```

Comment: You can't, it's not in the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [Message.getJMSDestination()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSDestination%28%29). It will return a [javax.jms.Destination](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Destination.html) which has no methods but will cast into a [javax.jms.[Temporary]Topic](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Topic.html) or a [javax.jms.[Temporary]Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Queue.html) which in turn have [getQueueName](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Queue.html#getQueueName%28%29) and [getTopicName](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Topic.html#getTopicName%28%29) methods respectively. (Calling **toString** will usually render something useful, but that's implementation specific.)